# How can I send data from a form to a class and visualize it?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass some data collected from a form and pass it to a class and visualize them, I have a problem sending the data, since I can not pick it up

```js
        class F1{

            constructor(num,clien,direc,nife,nifd,div,sub,iva){
                this.num = num
                this.clien = clien
                this.direc = direc
                this.nife = nife
                this.nifd = nifd
                this.div = div
                this.sub = sub
                this.iva = iva
            }
        }
```

```html
   <form name="formu" id="formu">
        num:
        <input type="text" name="num" value=""><br><br>
        clien:
        <input type="text" name="clien" value=""><br><br>
        direc:
        <input type="text" name="direc" value=""><br><br>
        NIFe:
        <input type="text" name="nife" value=""><br><br>
        NIFd:
        <input type="text" name="nifd" value=""><br><br>
        div:
        <input type="text" name="div" value=""><br><br>
        sub:
        <input type="text" name="sub" value=""><br><br>
        iva:
        <input type="text" name="iva" value=""><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

*Thanks*

Comment: _"visualize them"_ - what means visualize them, just displaying entered values?. _"I can not pick it up"_ - why? What's the problem in getting an input value?

Comment: @kezer keep me updated ... if my answer was helpful

Comment: @lucifer63 I can not collect the data because it is not sent from the form to the class and from this can see the data on screen (not console.log), what I need as a final result is to see the data of an invoice (address, client, number,...)

Comment: @Ferdinando yes, thanks to been helpful

Comment: @kezer You are welcome :).. If the answer to been helpful you can vote it..there is a flag....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If i understood your question you can try this code:

i used setter and getter; document.forms.
for more information you can read:

w3schools:[setter and getter](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp)

w3schools: [forms validation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp)

another link where you can try other information is:https://developer.mozilla.org/

**JS**

```
//object userInput
var userInput = {
  num:"",
  clien:"",
  direc:"",
  nife:"",
  nifd:"",
  div:"",
  sub:"",
  iva:"",
  //method set
  set setNum(num){
    this.num=num;
  },
  set setClien(clien){
    this.clien=clien;
  },
  set setDirec(direc){
    this.direc=direc;
  },
  set setNife(nife){
    this.nife=nife;
  },
  set setNifd(nifd){
    this.nifd=nifd;
  },
  set setDiv(div){
    this.div=div;
  },
  set setSub(sub){
    this.sub=sub;
  },
  set setIva(iva){
    this.iva=iva;
  },
  //method get
  get getNum(){
   return this.num;
  },
  get getClien(){
   return this.clien;
  },
  get getDirec(){
   return this.direc;
  },
  get getNife(){
   return this.nife;
  },
  get getNifd(){
   return this.nifd;
  },
  get getDiv(){
   return this.div;
  },
  get getSub(){
   return this.sub;
  },
  get getIva(){
   return this.iva;
  }
};

function myFunction2(){
  const myForm=document.forms["formu"];//form

 //put into object UserInput the user value
  userInput.setNum=myForm["num"].value;
  userInput.setClien=myForm["clien"].value;
  userInput.setDirec=myForm["direc"].value;
  //and so on...

  //print the value present in userInput object
  console.log(userInput.getNum);
  console.log(userInput.getClien);
  console.log(userInput.getDirec);

  return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <form name="formu" id="formu" action="" onsubmit="return myFunction2()" method="post">
    num:
    <input type="text" name="num" value=""><br><br>
    clien:
    <input type="text" name="clien" value=""><br><br>
    direc:
    <input type="text" name="direc" value=""><br><br>
    NIFe:
    <input type="text" name="nife" value=""><br><br>
    NIFd:
    <input type="text" name="nifd" value=""><br><br>
    div:
    <input type="text" name="div" value=""><br><br>
    sub:
    <input type="text" name="sub" value=""><br><br>
    iva:
    <input type="text" name="iva" value=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Snippet code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA_Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title> Form</title>
  <script>
  //object userInput
var userInput = {
  num:"",
  clien:"",
  direc:"",
  nife:"",
  nifd:"",
  div:"",
  sub:"",
  iva:"",
  //method set
  set setNum(num){
    this.num=num;
  },
  set setClien(clien){
    this.clien=clien;
  },
  set setDirec(direc){
    this.direc=direc;
  },
  set setNife(nife){
    this.nife=nife;
  },
  set setNifd(nifd){
    this.nifd=nifd;
  },
  set setDiv(div){
    this.div=div;
  },
  set setSub(sub){
    this.sub=sub;
  },
  set setIva(iva){
    this.iva=iva;
  },
  //method get
  get getNum(){
   return this.num;
  },
  get getClien(){
   return this.clien;
  },
  get getDirec(){
   return this.direc;
  },
  get getNife(){
   return this.nife;
  },
  get getNifd(){
   return this.nifd;
  },
  get getDiv(){
   return this.div;
  },
  get getSub(){
   return this.sub;
  },
  get getIva(){
   return this.iva;
  }
};

function myFunction2(){
  const myForm=document.forms["formu"];//form

 //put into object UserInput the user value
  userInput.setNum=myForm["num"].value;
  userInput.setClien=myForm["clien"].value;
  userInput.setDirec=myForm["direc"].value;
  //and so on...

  //print the value present in userInput object
  console.log(userInput.getNum);
  console.log(userInput.getClien);
  console.log(userInput.getDirec);

  return false;
}

  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="formu" id="formu" action="" onsubmit="return myFunction2()" method="post">
num:
<input type="text" name="num" value=""><br><br>
clien:
<input type="text" name="clien" value=""><br><br>
direc:
<input type="text" name="direc" value=""><br><br>
NIFe:
<input type="text" name="nife" value=""><br><br>
NIFd:
<input type="text" name="nifd" value=""><br><br>
div:
<input type="text" name="div" value=""><br><br>
sub:
<input type="text" name="sub" value=""><br><br>
iva:
<input type="text" name="iva" value=""><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @kezer if you want more information you can post them and I hope to answer your question...